# django-graphos, how to get example working?

Tags: javascript, django

Trying to hack a simple example of django-graphos working using the code below.  However I am getting 'Uncaught ReferencError $ is not defined' in Chrome inspector - red error dot showing just after $(function () { - and no graph appears, although it looks like the template is otherwise being generated correctly, as show in the inspector output below (don't have enough 'reputation to post an image).

Chrome Inspector Output:

```
<html>
<h1>- Django-graphos Chart 1 - </h1>
<head>
        <script type = "text/javascript" src = "js/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
        <script src = "js/flot/jquery.flot.js"></script>
     <div id="xlZGoSiTTr" style="width:800px;height:400px;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $.plot(
        $("#xlZGoSiTTr"), 
        [{"data": [["2004", 1000], ["2005", 1170], ["2006", 660], ["2007", 1030]], "label": "Sales"}, {"data": [["2004", 400], ["2005", 460], ["2006", 1120], ["2007", 540]], "label": "Expenses"}], 
        {"series": {"lines": {"show": "true"}}, "legend": {"position": "ne"}, "title": "Chart"}
    );
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import RequestContext, loader
from graphos.sources.simple import SimpleDataSource
from graphos.renderers import flot
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response


def do_graph(request):
    # get data
    data = [
    ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
    ['2004', 1000, 400],
    ['2005', 1170, 460],
    ['2006', 660, 1120],
    ['2007', 1030, 540]
    ]
    chart = flot.LineChart(SimpleDataSource(data=data))
    #context = RequestContext( request, `enter code here`{'chart':chart.as_html(),'data':data})
    #template = loader.get_template('chart.html')
    #return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
    #return render(request, 'chart.html')
    return render_to_response('chart.html', {'chart': chart})
```

chart.html:

```
<html>
<h1>- Django-graphos Chart 1 - </h1>
<head>
        <script type = "text/javascript" src = "{{ STATIC_URL }}js/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
        <script type = "text/javascript" src = "{{ STATIC_URL }}js/flot/jquery.flot.js"></script>
     {{chart.as_html}}
</head>
<body>
<div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The two javascript files seems to be being found ok, with a status 200 returned by the django development server for both files. Can't seem to locate a simple working example for django-graphos, so any suggestions for a fix would be appreciated.  Best wishes, Ron.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question!
The problem was simply a bad expression accessing the jquery javascript files, despite the nginx log indicating that the files had been retrieved, i.e. 200 status.

Here is the syntax that works (more code has been added since the original question to run various Flot features)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.tab { margin-left: 220px; }
</style>
        <script type = "text/javascript" src = "/static/js/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
        <script type = "text/javascript" src = "/static/js/flot/jquery.flot.js"></script>
        <script type = "text/javascript" src = "/static/js/flot/jquery.flot.time.js"></script>
        <script type = "text/javascript" src="/static/js/flot/date.js"></script>
        <script type = "text/javascript" src="/static/js/flot/jquery.flot.axislabels.js"></script>
<p class="tab"><font size=28 color="red">- Tank Water Level - </font></p>
        {{chart.as_html}}
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

The views.py file was correct.  It is now working with Flot chart options as shown below.  The get_table() function simply returns a n x 2 data matrix, with field names in the first row.

```
def do_graph(request):
    # get data
    data = get_table()
    chart = flot.LineChart(SimpleDataSource(data=data),options={'series':{'color':'orange'}, 'lines': {'lineWidth': 2, 'fill':1, 'fillColor': {'colors':["rgba(0, 0, 153, 0.4)","rgba(255, 255, 255,0.4)"]} }, 'points':{'symbol':'circle'},'xaxis':{'mode':'time', 'timezone':'browser', 'axisLabel':'Date Time', 'axisLabelUseCanvas':'true', 'axisLabelFontSizePixels': 20,'axisLabelFontFamily':'Arial','color':'red'},'yaxis':{'min':50, 'max':400, 'tickSize': 50, 'axisLabel':'Centimeters', 'axisLabelUseCanvas':'true', 'axisLabelFontSizePixels': 20,'axisLabelFontFamily':'Arial'},'grid':{'color':800}})
    return render_to_response('chart.html', {'chart': chart})
```

The Flot options and additional jquery plugins generate a graph that shows date time properly on the x-axis, with the first column of the data comprising javascript timestamps. Axis labels are plotted using the additional 'axislabels' jquery flot plugin.

Best wishes
Ron